# FirebaseNodeJS: Function - getUid is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the uid of a user based off their email address in my functions file:

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail("email@email.com")
        .then(function(userRecord) {
          response.json({
            uid: userRecord.getUid(),
          })
        console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.toJSON());
```

However in my logs for the function -

```
Error fetching user data: TypeError: userRecord.getUid is not a function
```

My console.log is all OK for userRecord.toJSON but I am trying to return the uid back to the front end. Any suggestions? Am I missing something as this should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `uid` property of the [`UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.userrecord?hl=en) as follows:

```
response.json({
  uid: userRecord.uid,
})
```

As you can see in the doc, a `UserRecord` does not have a `getUid()` method.